# Send a message from Arduino via bluetooth to Windows Phone 8

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8, arduino

I am wondering weather I can send a simple message like "hello" to windows phone 8 through the Arduino mega board.I am a beginner to Arduino and everything is still too much complicated.

Pin configurations

- Tx of Bluetooth module to Rx3 of mega (pin 15)
- Rx of Bluetooth module to Tx3 of Mega (pin 14)

If you can provide me with a simple examples of C# and a Arduino that would would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example of Bluetooth communication between an Arduino and a Windows Phone here:

[Windows Phone 8 communicating with Arduino using Bluetooth](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth)